# Error with gets

Tags: c++

I the below mentioned program:

```
string s;
cout<<"Enter a string:";
gets(s);
```

I expect my input to be of the form: "Hilton Hotels".

On using gets, I get the following error:

```
 error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* gets(char*)’
```

I can not use "cin" as I want my input to consist of space and special characters like '_' etc, also I want my delimiter to be 'enter'. Is there some other way...or please be kind enough in correcting the error.

Comment: "Error with gets" is a tautology.  Never use gets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gets` isn't very c++ (it's for compatibility with C). Use this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Also, look at [`std::ios::skipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) and [`<iomanip>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) for whitespace handling options

Answer (score 0):

> I can not use "cin" as I want my input to consist of space and special characters

You can use `cin`.

> Is there some other way...or please be kind enough in correcting the error.

`gets` receives a `char*`, so use a `char*` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

First issue: 'gets' takes a char array to read into. You can't give it an stl string, that doesn't make any sense. You'd need to do something like

```
char buf[1024];
gets(buf);
```

Second issue: 'gets' is from the older C stdio library. You shouldn't try to mix stdio access with C++ style i/o - each library maintains it's own buffering and only confusion will result. If you use one for input and the other for output you might get away with it, but it's a bad idea - learn to use the C++ style of input to do what you want (std::getline, is, I think, the routine you need).

Third, BIG HONKING issue: 'gets' is one one of those nasty hold-over functions from way back in the early days of C and CAN NOT be used safely. DO NOT TRY TO USE 'gets' EVER.

The problem is that 'gets' has no idea what the size of the buffer it's reading into is, so it's always capable of overflowing that buffer and over-writing memory (causing all sorts of potential problems). NEVER try to use gets in ANYTHING. If you want to do stdio-style input, use

```
fgets(buf, bufsize, stdin)
```

which takes a buffer size and won't over-run it's input buffer.